# LinqPad row id not getting updated after SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, datacontext, linqpad

```
Node n = new Node(){
    Title = "test"
};
Nodes.InsertOnSubmit(n);
SubmitChanges();
n.Id.Dump();
```

It will dump 0.

In the database table, the row is inserted with the correct (auto-incremented) id. I'm just wondering if this is a setup issue since I'm using the IQ driver with MySql.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct - this is a limitation in the IQ driver.

Comment: Okay thanks Joe. It's not a big problem for me. But hopefully, it will get resolved sometimes in the future.

Comment: Joe, 
I had the same issue, of not retrieving the auto-incremented id, with my VFP LINQPad provider (which uses IQToolkit).  If you are interested, you can see how I resolved the issue...  http://www.randomdevnotes.com/2011/06/retrieving-auto-generated-primary-key-values-on-insert/